# How to download files from text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have multiple text files such as `a0001.txt`, `a0002.txt`, upto `a0900.txt` containing direct image links https://example.com/photos/example.jpg.

I want to batch download all links from `a0001.txt` to `a0001` folder and so on in respective folder names as text file.

Links must be download in order so images renamed with prefix, for sorting purposes.

What I tried was below, but it downloading one file at a time super slow, any other way to do it in parallel?

```
#! /usr/bin/env
bashif [ -z $1 ] || egrep -qv '^https?:\/\/[^[:space:]]+' $1; then
  echo "Usage: $0 FILE"
  echo "FILE must be a newline-separated list of URLs."
  exit
fi

INPUT_FILE=$1
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="${INPUT_FILE%.*}"

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

i=1
while read URL; do
  FILENAME="${URL##*/}"
  curl -L $URL > "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${i}_${FILENAME}"
  i=$(($i+1))
done < $INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Is your shebang line really `#! /usr/bin/env` or did you mean `#! /usr/bin/env bash`?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: You can start the `curl` processes in parallel by appending `&` to the end of the command. But you should not start too many processes. For example in every ten iterations, you can run a `wait` command.

Comment: Read `man seq` for generating the "`A00001, ..., A0900` strings. Append "`&`" to your `curl`" command.